# gdal.Translate with projection

Tags: python, gdal

this command line tool works:

```
gdal_translate -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co JPEG_QUALITY=100 -a_nodata none -co INTERLEAVE=BAND -scale -ot Byte T11VPC\S2A_L1C_20190708T191921_N0208_R099_T10UDD_A.tif T11VPC\S2A_L1C_20190708T191921_N0208_R099_T10UDD_V_JPEG.jpg
```

however then i try to use it in gdal.Translate it produces file without the projection:

```
translateoptions = gdal.TranslateOptions(gdal.ParseCommandLine("-co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co JPEG_QUALITY=100 -a_nodata none -co INTERLEAVE=BAND -scale -ot Byte"))
gdal.Translate(out_img, in_ds, options=translateoptions)
```

how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could try making sure you're using the full path name in the python code instead of a path relative to where you're running.  Also, I usually like to set the GDAL_DATA configuration option to specify where the gdalbin directory is located in case it's needed.  Other than that, I'm not sure what the problem would be without additional information and example files.

Comment: you can try, this is the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ST6i9fjot0pff15kmMspBp3-r3hLfAM3/view?usp=sharing,  i am using the GDAL 3.0.2